# Flagging questions which aren't worth an answer

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons, question-quality

I've read a few Meta questions and answers on this topic already, but I am still not sure how I should handle a question like [Java Different Instant Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187710/java-different-instant-values). I would say it's not even worth an answer, as common sense would answer the question.

So, how should we flag such questions? Should they be flagged as "too broad" or "unclear" (the question is neither)?

This is the body of the question for reference in case it gets deleted:

> Why does the following code returns two different Instant values when
>   printed out?
>
> ```
> Timestamp currentTime = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
>
> System.out.println(currentTime.toInstant());
> System.out.println(Instant.now());
> ```
>
> When printing out the above two
>   lines, it will give me:
>
> 2018-01-10T12:22:46.168Z
>
> AND
>
> 2018-01-10T12:22:46.236Z

Comment: You don't. 'worth an answer' is a judgement call, not a topic policy.

Comment: So you say we don't flag this kind of question and just let them live, even tho nobody will profit from them?

Comment: Who says nobody will benefit? Just because *you* don't think it is useful, doesn't mean others have to agree there.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer usually very simple questions have duplicates, so if you can find one, vote/flag to close it as a duplicate.  The example you gave might have a duplicate that deals with type assignments in Java (although it might go over the head of the person who asked the question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't. You made a value judgement, and we don't have off-topic reasons for that.

You use *voting* for that; the tooltip on the downvote button says: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear **or not useful***; you feel the question is not useful, so you would downvote it.

The question is otherwise on topic. If others want to answer the question, then that's perfectly fine.